# Best way to do Cross tabulation over same column with R

Tags: r, t-sql

I have the following case in which a `TSQL` procedure a bit slow and i'm looking for substitude possibly in `R`:

```
I want to do a cross tabulation over example table:

surveyID    QuestionID  AnswerID
1000        1       1
1000        2       3
1000        3       2
1000        4       1
1001        1       3
1001        2       2
1001        3       1
1001        4       3
```

And to get results like :

```
QuestionIDx QuestionIDy AnswerIDx   AnswerIDy   Frequancy
1       1       1       2       x
1       1       1       3       x
1       1       2       3       x
.....
```

I am basically left joining the table by it self on `surveyID` and then i use R's functions `table` or `xtabs` to get the frequencies.

```
INSERT INTO #CrossTabResults([ProtoQuestionIDx], [ProtoQuestionIDy], [AnswerPosIDx], [AnswerPosIDy], [Frequency])
    EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
  @language =N'R',
  @script=N'
  OutputDataSet <- data.frame(table(InputDataSet$ProtoQuestionIDx, InputDataSet$ProtoQuestionIDy, InputDataSet$AnswerPosIDx, InputDataSet$AnswerPosIDy))
  ', @input_data_1 = N'SELECT [SurveyInstanceID], [ProtoQuestionIDx], [ProtoQuestionIDy], [AnswerPosIDx], [AnswerPosIDy] FROM  #JoinedSurveys'


OR



    INSERT INTO #CrossTabResults([ProtoQuestionIDx], [ProtoQuestionIDy], [AnswerPosIDx], [AnswerPosIDy], [Frequency])
    EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
  @language =N'R',
  @script=N'
  OutputDataSet <- data.frame(xtabs(~ ProtoQuestionIDx + ProtoQuestionIDy + AnswerPosIDx + AnswerPosIDy, data=InputDataSet))
  ', @input_data_1 = N'SELECT [SurveyInstanceID], [ProtoQuestionIDx], [ProtoQuestionIDy], [AnswerPosIDx], [AnswerPosIDy] FROM  #JoinedSurveys'
```

I'm not sure that this is the right approach and also it doesn't improve execution speed. I'm looking for fastest solution. Any help is appreciated.